# Row number is not displaying first and last row number in paginated table in php

Tags: php, html, pagination

I am implementing a website in which admin has access to maintain stock. I am displaying stock from the database in html table. i have used pagination to display 10 records per page. I want that when i am on page 1 it displays "Showing 1-10 of total record" and when i am on page 2 it displays "Showing 11-20 of total record" and vice versa.
CODE:

```
<?php          
                $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
                mysql_select_db("login", $link);    
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM add_stock");
                $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
                $num = $row[0];

                ?>
    <table align="center" border="0" id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list">
            <tr>
              <th>Sr.No</th>
              <th>Product Code</th>
              <th>Brand</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>Gender</th>
              <th>Category</th>
              <th>Material</th>
              <th>Size</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th><b>Image</b></th>
              </tr> 
    $num_rec_per_page=10;

                    if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
                    $start_from = ($page-1) * $num_rec_per_page; 
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM add_stock  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page"; 
                    $rs_result = mysql_query ($sql); //run the query
                    $total_records = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);  //count number of records
                    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 

                    $next_page = $page + 1;
                    $prev_page = $page - 1;
                     $i= $start_from;
                     $start=1;
                    while ($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs_result) )
                    {                
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $i+$start; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result['id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result['brand_name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result['price']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result['gender_name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result['category_name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result['material_name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result['size_name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result['dress_description']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result['dress_quantity']; ?></td>

                    <td><a href="javascript:window.open('<?php echo $result['image'] ?>','mypopuptitle', '_parent')" >View Image</a></td>
                  </tr>

                  <?php
                  $i++; 
                } ?>
                </table>
                 <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM add_stock"; 
                    $rs_result = mysql_query($sql); //run the query
                    $total_records = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);  //count number of records
                    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 
                    ?> 
                    <div style="margin-left: 5px;">
                    <div class="pagination">
                    <?php
                    echo "<a href='viewstock.php?page=1'><b>&laquo;</b></a>";
                    if ($page==1) {
                    $page=1;
                    }
                    else{
                    echo "<a href='viewstock.php?page=$prev_page'><b>Prev</b></a>"; }
                    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
                    echo "<a href='viewstock.php?page=".$i."'><b>".$i."</b></a>";
                    }
                    if ($page==$total_pages) {
                    $page=$total_pages;
                    }
                    else{
                    echo "<a href='viewstock.php?page=$next_page'><b>Next</b></a>"; }
                    echo "<a href='viewstock.php?page=$total_pages'><b>&raquo;</b></a> ";
                    ?> 
                    </div>
                    </div>

<p>Displaying <?php echo $start ?> - <?php echo $total_records ?>  of Records: <?php echo $num ?></p>
```

Comment: i want that it should display text in paragraph tag(that is at top before table tag)  that showing 1 - 10 records on page 1 and when i am on page 2 it should display text showing 11 - 20 records

Comment: using `mysql_query`? Still, in 2017? It's been deprecated for years and removed entirely in PHP7, largely due to security issues. For instance a major issue is that it doesn't let you create parameterised queries and prepared statements and consequently, code like yours is very vulnerable to SQL injection attacks which could be used to steal, corrupt or destroy your data. You should really switch to `mysqli` or `PDO` a.s.a.p. http://bobby-tables.com has an explanation of the risks and some examples of how to write your queries safely.

Comment: Aside from that horrow show, you've told us what you want, but not what the problem is with the code. What does it do now?

Comment: its not displaying that text it only display total number of records but not showing 1-10 of total records

Comment: ok well that's because you haven't written any code which would do that. have you actually tried to do it? You just need to output the start and end values (which you must know, in order to run the query). Looks like maybe you don't calculate those values until lower down in the code, in which case you can just move the calculations higher up so you can use them in the necessary part of the output.

Comment: i have tried alot but not working. i just removed that part of code because its not working

Comment: well we can't fix code that we can't see. Anyway I just explained the likely reason it's not working, simply that the values you need haven't been calculated at that point. So you can just move the code that calculates them to an earlier position in the code. Do you agree?

Comment: Please check i edited the code

Comment: ok that's useful, but you still didn't say what it does wrong, which leaves me to try and work it out. But I can see trivially that $start is never incremented, so probably it always displays 1? And $num_rec_per_page is always 10, so it's just a static output. I would guess you want to be using $start_from and ($start_from + $num_rec_per_page)  as your two values.

Comment: Thanks it is now working perfectly for first value but not for last value

Comment: ok, so what does it produce? And what did you expect? You keep forgetting to explain the detail of the problem. "Not working" is not a sufficient description of the problem. I cannot read your mind, or your screen.

Comment: sorry for that,

Comment: <p >Displaying <?php echo $start_from+1 ?> - <?php echo $start_from + $num_rec_per_page ?>  of Records: <?php echo $num ?></p> it displays 11 of 20 on page 2 while i have only 18 records in my database. it means starting value it takes is right but last value it takes total numbaer of alloweded records in page that is 10

Comment: ok so then you need to use $start_from + $total_records I should think, since $total_records tells you how many records were actually returned for the page.

Comment: no total_records actually tells total number of records in database

Comment: ah yes, but only because you re-assign it a new value after the `SELECT * FROM add_stock` query. So just give the second $total_records a different name, and then you can use the first version of it in your output. Re-using the same variable name for 2 different meanings is a bad practice which comes back to confuse us in cases like this - don't do it!

Comment: Thanks alot its working perfect now :)

Comment: No problem. I will write it up as a proper answer, so it can be accepted by you, and usable by future readers/.

Comment: yes sure :) please do that

Comment: that's done now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
<p>Displaying <?php echo $start_from+1 ?> - <?php echo $start_from + $total_records ?> of Records: <?php echo $num ?></p>
```

as long as you:

1) Move the output below the code where the numbers you need are calculated

2) Don't re-use the variable `$total_records` after your `SELECT * FROM add_stock`. Instead give this instance of the variable a new name so it can't be confused with the earlier version, which means something different, and is needed for your output.

Please note also my first comment regarding your SQL Injection vulnerability, which you should take steps to fix as soon as possible.